# Hubspot integration form data syncs only after logging in to craft cms control panel

Tags: integration

Currently I have set up the new integration using Hubspot's private app's access token for my craft cms site. The integration seems to be working fine except that the messages from my craft cms form only syncs to hubspot when I log into my craft cms control panel.

There are also no error messages in the log and I have tried refreshing the integration too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default any queue jobs for Craft only run when the control panel has been hit. You'll need a cron job or queue worker (such as Laravel Forge's daemons) to run these with no one logged on.

This is a really good guide to Craft queues, written by Andrew Welch from NYStudio107, it tends to be a go-to resource for this scenario

https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms

> **But how do the queue jobs run? Here’s how:**
>
> - When some­one access the CP
> - Via web request Here­in lies the rub with
>
> the default queue imple­men­ta­tion in Craft CMS. No queue jobs will
> run at all unless some­one logs into the CP, and even then, they are
> run via web request.

Comment: thank you for your answer , I was kind of in the dark regarding this problem ! I decided to go with the first solution in the article which was the async queue craft plugin, as it seemed to be easier and simpler and it worked perfectly